# Архитектура и методы для нейросетевого классификатора

Tags: python, pandas, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, pytorch

Подскажите ответ на вопрос:

**Вводные**: Есть многомерный набор данных, использующийся как вход для сети. Есть бинарный выход - 1 или 0.

**Проблема**: В наборе данных не у всех есть зависимость выхода от входа. Что я имею в виду: в датасете есть строки, у которых выход +- стабилен при том же входе, а есть те, у которых выход - рандомный. В качестве примера: прогнозируем погоду. Имеем много фичей на вход, и, например, один выход - будет ли шторм в море, или нет. Дело в том, что при определенных стечениях вводных параметров шторм почти всегда будет/не будет. Например, если ветер больше 10 м/с, его направление - Юго-западное, погода пасмурная. В остальных случаях четкой зависимости нет, иначе говоря, если на входе другие значения - результат не предсказуем. И требуется найти именно те вводные данные, при которых результат прогнозируется.

**Вопрос 1**: Как это сделать? Есть ли способ заставить сеть обучаться таким образом, чтобы условно-похожие данные с условно-похожим результатом давали ответ, а рандомные данные - нет?

**Вопрос 2**: Самый простой вариант - просто запустить обучаться сеть и надеяться, что она сама сможет выцепить нужные ей параметры. Но здесь есть серьезная проблема: сеть, пытаясь минимизировать ошибку, обучается в соответствии с данным ей в обучении выходом. Иными словами - если в Y при обучении единиц больше, чем нулей - она начинает всегда выдавать единицу, и наоборот (что кажется логичным, ведь задача сети минимизировать ошибку, так что она просто подгоняет ответ в зависимости от распределения результата). Такое происходит и в обычной сети из Dense слоев, и в градиентом бустинге CatBoost. Пробовал с разными функциями активации, и все мимо. Как этого избежать? Какую архитектуру лучше использовать (все данные цифровые)?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

UPD: Картинка ко второму вопросу - вот такой результат выдает сеть:[image: Результат работы сети]

Вместо частокола она просто выдает всегда единицу, хотя соотношение 0 и 1 там примерно 60 на 40.

Comment: Чтобы вам помочь нужно видеть архитектуру вашей сети.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy дело в том, что ее нет. Или простой CatBoostClassifier, или просто несколько Dense слоев. Я не могу придумать, какую архитектуру можно придумать для решения задачи, возможно, какие-то специальные функции потерь, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Тут нет решения по сути, есть просто несколько компромиссов: есть вариант убрать те строки в которых выход не зависит от входа-то есть рандомен, тогда модель будет в нормальных случаях предсказывать хорошо, а в некоторых плохо и есть вариант обогащать данные, пытаться найти какие то новые данные, которых на данный момент у вас в таблице нет, но которые могут помочь в нахождении зависимости для модели.

Comment: @Step1709 проблема в том, что мне заранее неизвестны комбинации, в которых результат не рандомен, я это и пытаюсь определить с помощью сети. Если бы я знал, то да, выкинул бы и проблем бы не было, но увы. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) отбрасывает часть данных, которые не согласуются с моделью. Время обучения возрастает многократно, конечно.